# Emacs Org Mode Habits - 3 out of 4 Days

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm attempting to put together a habit in Org Mode that needs to be checked in every 3 out of 4 days (specifically, 3 days on, 1 day off).  I'm not entirely certain that this is even possible with the repeating schedule syntax, but wanted to ask and see if anyone has been able to figure this out.